# Decoding byte[] to string[][]

Tags: java, android, sql

I am storing a string[][]-array into a database as a "blob". Loading the data, I initially get a byte[]-array, which I then need to decode to string[][] again.

So: Can anywone tell me if there is a way to convert a byte[]-array to a string[][]-array (on Android)?
Or if there is a way to convert a byte[]-array to an ArrayList ?

I asked a similar question once, but the question was referring to blobs.

Comment: Can you explain why you would need something like this?

Comment: What does it mean to convert a 1D array to a 2D array, let alone 2D array of `String`? What's the conversion rule? It normally makes sense to talk about *decoding* a `byte[]` to a `String`. This seems off by two whole dimensions!

Comment: Well, I am storing a string[][]-array to a database as a "blob". Loading the data, I initially get a byte-array, which I then need to decode to a string[][]-array.

Comment: "I am storing". Can you clearify? What magic is applied to make your string[][] a blob (byte[]) in DB?

Comment: I simply stored the string[][]-array "as is" with  "INSERT INTO..." into a column with "blob" as datatype.

Answer (score 3):

You would normally convert a byte array to a *single* blob - why would you want an *array* of blobs? Would you want a single blob per byte? That sounds unlikely.

Creating a single blob for an array of bytes is easy though... for example, with a `PreparedStatement`:

```
statement.setBlob(parameterIndex, bytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please see my edited initial post which now specifies what I want to achieve by this conversion.

Comment: @deimos: Now your title talks about converting byte arrays *to* blobs, while your question talks about converting blobs to strings. Which is it?

Comment: Eventually I need to convert a byte[]-array to a string[][]-array. To do this the way presented in my initial post, I would need a blob-array, not a byte-array. So if either one of the questions is answered, it would help me a lot.

Comment: @deimos1988: It's not clear why you need to get a blob involved at all. Do you *just* need to convert byte arrays into strings? If so, please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: I changed the title to what I eventually need. If you know how to accomplish that, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @deimos: It's still unclear - you have an array of bytes - how on earth are we meant to know how you want them split up into a string array? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - help us to help you by giving us more information.

Comment: I edited my post again, including all the information I can think of. I hope it is enough.

Comment: @deimos1988: That's still not enough information. How did you first convert your `string[][]` into a blob?

Comment: I didn't convert it at all. I put the string[][]-array "as is" with  "INSERT INTO..." into a column with "blob" as datatype.

Comment: @deimos1988: Well that's going to make it awkward, if you've no idea how it was stored. If you could show us the exact code you used for that, it would help... I wouldn't be surprised if you find you've lost data though.

Comment: The exact code is a simple sql-command: myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +QueryInput.MY_DATABASE_TABLE+ " (res) VALUES('"+result+"');"); "result" is a string[][]-array.

Comment: @deimos1988: Oh, that's quite bad. The latter part of your SQL will have been converted into something like `"VALUES ([[Ljava.lang.String;@3e25a5)"` because that's what happens when you call `toString()` on a `String[][]`. You've not actually stored any of the data. I do hope you haven't done this with *actual* data you wanted to keep... and it shows the importance of giving as much information as possible in the question.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for the clarification. So how would I need to store the string[][]-array so it is actually saved, and so that I can load it again later?

Comment: @deimos1988: Rather than do this in comments, I suggest you post that as a separate question.

Comment: Okay, I just asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809179/storing-a-string-array-in-a-database