# Storing a string[][]-Array in a database

Tags: java, android, serialization

I would like to store a string[][]-array in a database as datatype "blob". I just found out that I have to convert it, otherwise the data would be practically lost.
What would be the best way to do that?

I suppose I should serialize and de-serialize the array, unfortunately I am not quite experienced in that area. So any help would be appreciated.

PS: I guess I should have said that I need to do that on Android, thus using SQLite. The string[][] has no fixed number of rows or columns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

The main problem was that apparently the BLOB has not been saved properly in the database. I used the Android convenience methods to update the database, and now it works even better than I first anticipated.

Comment: Down-voted for accepting your own answer without giving a specific solution. What "Android convenience methods"?

Answer (score 3):

Why a blob? Why not a clob?  Or better yet, why not a varchar? Depending on what you're going to do with the data, you should store the data as xml or json in a varchar column.  It would be searchable too, if necessary.

You didn't say what's in your array but possibly another table would fit the bill, though determining that is far outside the scope of this question (it would make a good new question though).

No, far better to serialize your array as text and store it as such.

Edit... A library like [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) supports bi-directional serialization on multidimensional arrays.  Just run your array through JSON-lib to get a JSON string, store that string, then when you want your array back run the string through JSON-lib.

I prefer my text to be in the database as text so I can search for it and view it with one of the many database tools available.  I don't want to run code to see what's in a column, and if I need to tweak a value by hand during development I want to be able to update the value, not run a program to do it for me.

Comment: If you're going to convert it to XML or JSON, you've still got to write the code to convert it to an XML document or JSON object, and then convert it back later on. Then you've got "text within text" escaping to potentially worry about, which isn't required in something like the binary format I demonstrated.

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't need to write code for the conversion - I use libraries for that.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, assuming there won't be nulls. Write out:

- The number of "rows" as a fixed 4-byte value

  - For each "row":
  - The number of "columns" as a fixed 4-byte value
  - For each string:

    - Convert the string in bytes, e.g. in UTF-8 (`text.getBytes("UTF-8")`)
    - Write out the number of bytes as a fixed 4-byte value
    - Write out the data for the string

You *could* just use `DataOutputStream`'s `writeUTF` method for the last part, but that would make it slightly harder to read from non-Java platforms. It depends on your requirements. Using `DataOutputStream` would make it easier to handle in general though. For example:

```
private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

private static byte[] SerializeText(String[][] array)
{
    int rows = array.length;

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeInt(rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int columns = array[i].length;
        dos.writeInt(columns);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            byte[] utf8 = array[i][j].getBytes(UTF8);
            dos.writeInt(utf8.length);
            dos.write(utf8, 0, utf8.length);
        }
    }
    dos.flush(); // May not be necessary
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Phew, that's a lot of work to store some strings. From his question it sounds like he came up with a solution (blob) and is trying to find code to make it work. There's no reason Strings need to be converted to binary to be stored in a db.

Comment: @Paul: Um, have a look at his previous question to see what his previous "solution" was. And yes, if you want to store *a two-dimensional array* of strings in a database (in one value), converting them into a binary form seems to be a good idea.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree. If I store text in my database then I want to be able to search for it or at least view it with something like SQL Developer or Toad. A library like [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) supports bi-directional serialization on multidimensional arrays. What could be simpler?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately each row may have a different number of columns, values can't be null though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thank you again very much for your answer. As I've stated in my question however, I have almost no experience in this area. How would I deserialize the data? Using DataInputStream?

Comment: @deimos1988: Yes - basically you reverse the steps. Read the number of rows, then from each row you read the number of columns, then for each column read the size of the string, read the string data and then convert it back into a string.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Unfortunately I still don't really how exactly to procede; however I experienced another issue: when I serialize the array and use the DataInputReader.getInt-method on the serialized array, I get the correct value. If I load the serialized array from the database, the value is 1531068468. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @deimos, what value were you expecting?

Comment: @Paul I was excpecting 301. Is it possible that I shouldn't store a byte-array in the database (with blob as datatype in the specified column), but maybe as blob right away? Maybe some data was lost when storing it in the db as byte[]?

Comment: @deimos1988: What do you mean by "when I serialize the array"? Again, complete code would help. I think you should work on managing to correctly store an arbitrary byte array first (e.g. a test pattern of 00 01 02 03) and then tackle this bigger issue.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I meant that when the string[][]-array was coded as a byte[]-array and then again decoded, everything worked fine. But when I saved that byte[]-array in the database, loaded it from there and tried to decode it again, above mentioned nonsense appeared.

Comment: @deimos: Yes, which is why I suggested that you separate the two problems - work on storing just byte arrays (starting with a simple, easily-recognized one) and retrieving them. Then build on that to store the string array. If you're having problems with the "just byte array" bit, I suggest you open another question. A lot of good software engineering is just breaking a big problem into lots of little ones...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I did what you suggested and it turns out, there really is some kind of problem retrieving the data from the db. When i do the following: byte[] bytetest = new byte[]{'5'}, I can easily decode it with "new String(bytetest)". If I store "bytetest" to the db, load it and decode it, I get "[B@450bc010��" (the correct byte representation of "'5'" should be "[B@450bc010", without the "��").

Comment: @deimos: It sounds like you're passing the byte array in the same way as you did the string array in a previous question - directly in the SQL statement. That has exactly the same problem, namely it'll call toString. You should use a prepared statement and set a blob for the parameter.

Comment: @Jon Skeet My problem has been solved, thank you very much for trying to help me!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of XML, I just discovered a JSON library (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)), named [google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You just have to add the .jar to your classpath, and I give you the code for serialization and deserialization:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] fruits = { { "Banana", "Apple", "Blueberry" }, { "Cherry" }, { "Lemon", "Mango" } };

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Serialization
        String json = gson.toJson(fruits);

        // Print: [["Banana","Apple","Blueberry"],["Cherry"],["Lemon","Mango"]]
        System.out.println(json);

        // Deserialization
        String[][] result = gson.fromJson(json, String[][].class);

    }
}
```

I am really happy that I found this library, XML was too much verbose.

(Sorry for spelling mistakes, I am French.)

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as xml with the [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) library.

It is not very effective due to xml tags, but it works well and it is easy to use:

```
String[][] strs = {
    { "row1_col1", "row1_col2", "row1_col3" },
    { "row2_col1" },
    { "row3_col1", "row3_col2" }
};

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("saa", String[][].class);
xstream.alias("sa", String[].class);
xstream.alias("s", String.class);

String xml = xstream.toXML(str);

System.out.println(xml);
```

The result:

```
<saa>
  <sa>
    <s>row1_col1</s>
    <s>row1_col2</s>
    <s>row1_col3</s>
  </sa>
  <sa>
    <s>row2_col1</s>
  </sa>
  <sa>
    <s>row3_col1</s>
    <s>row3_col2</s>
  </sa>
</saa>
```

Deserialize:

```
String[][] strs = (String[][])xstream.fromXML(xml);
```